# How to change name of file uploaded with multer after calling post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I want to save the pictures using multer with uniqe names. The pattern for file name is `file.orginalName + req.body.userName`.

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer  = require('multer');
const bcrypt  = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');

let User = require('../models/user');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/avatars/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })


router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {

  ////here I want to change the uploaded avatar name then save to DB
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I change my code to rename the picture name inside post method?

Comment: You can pass custom name of file in place of `file.originalname`

Comment: but I can not pass there `req.body.username`, which I want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/avatars/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        //console.log(req.body)
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            //stuff when error while file uploading
        } else {
            //file uploaded
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: storage is not defined` then

Comment: Glad, it help :)